# Dynamically assign log message recipient | MS Enterprise Library 5.0 logger

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, enterprise-library

I have a WCF RESTful ws with logging enabled using MS Enterprise Library 5.0. Logging works fine, however, I need to dynamically assign log message recipient email address i.e. set by ws consumer identity, if X calls my ws, things must be logged to x@x.com, if y calls ws, then logs go to y@y.com. I know email addresses in advance.

I thought about adding a new category+logging target listener per each consumer and applying category to LogEvent by caller identity on the runtime, however this would be quite a big overhead. Is there any better way to do that?
I am new to wcf and MSEL, so maybe I missed something.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you are using `EmailTraceListener`. Correct?

Comment: @Rest: Yes, correct. EmailTraceListener is assigned to category in webconfig; I assign category to logEvent in the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to:

1. Implement custom trace listener data: Simply inherit from `EmailTraceListenerData`.
2. Implement custom trace listener assembler: Inherit from `EmailTraceListenerAssembler` and override `Assemble` method.
3. Implement custom trace listener: Inherit from `EmailTraceListener` and override `TraceData` and `Write` methods.
4. Set `type` and `listenerDataType` type to use custom trace listener and custom trace listener data.

Comment: I've the same requirement; I am using the EL version 5.0; seems like `EmailTraceListenerAssembler` class has disappeared in 5.0 :( Any alternatives? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Finally got this working. You need to follow these steps. A slightly modified version of Rest Wing's proposal (as `EmailTraceListenerAssembler` could not be found):

- Sub-class `EmailTraceListener` and override one or more of `TraceData` or `Write` methods.
- Sub-class `EmailTraceListenerData` and override `GetCreationExpression()` method. In the body of this method, make sure to use the sub-class created in the previous step. See the source dode of Enterprise Library.
- In the .config file, set `type` and `listenerDataType` type to use custom trace listener and custom trace listener data.